# reason for sqlalchemy to roll back

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy to store data into a postgresql database. I am a little bit confused that sqlalchemy rolls back on execution without throwing an exception. I found an [article in the documentary](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/faq.html#why-does-sqlalchemy-issue-so-many-rollbacks) and tried to prevent rollbacks by setting `pool_reset_on_return='commit'`

This actually leads sqlalchemy to do nothing. Hence, I inserted a line that explicitly calls `trans.commit()` that leads to the following output:

```
2014-03-03 18:03:33,390,p:32764 Thread-3, sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine(_execute_context) [INFO]: INSERT INTO _fd (**)
2014-03-03 18:03:33,391,p:32764 Thread-3, sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine(_execute_context) [INFO]: {****}
2014-03-03 18:03:33,392,p:32764 Thread-3, sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine(__init__) [DEBUG]: Col ('fid',)
2014-03-03 18:03:33,393,p:32764 Thread-3, sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine(process_rows) [DEBUG]: Row (*,)
2014-03-03 18:03:33,393,p:32764 Thread-3, sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine(_rollback_impl) [INFO]: ROLLBACK
```

The code is quit simple so far:

```
1837     with conn.begin() as trans:                                                                                                                                                                                                           
1838         statement = meta.tables[_table_name].insert().values(
...
1847         )
1848         res = conn.execute(statement)
1849         trans.commit()
```

Does anyone have an idea, what could be the cause for the rollbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have no glue on the reason of that habit, but putting a `conn.execute("commit")` at the end of the statement solves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Not 100% sure about the reason but looking at the [source](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py#L1232), we can see that when you do `trans.commit()` within your `with....` construct, it sets the transaction to inactive. Now when the `Context Manager` for the transaction tries to run the `__exit__()` method at the end of the `with` statement, it triggers a `rollback()` because the `is_active` flag has been set to False. (I don't know what happens when you commit a transaction and then roll it back).

Anyways the "problem" is that `with` construct handles the commit and rollback part implicitly. Per the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/connections.html#using-transactions), all you need to do is

```
with conn.begin() as trans:      
    statement = meta.tables[_table_name].insert().values(
    ...
    )
    res = conn.execute(statement)
```